# How to store position in spritekit

Tags: ios, xcode, game-engine, sprite-kit

I need to change the character appearance during the game. My character define by a node:

```
SKSpriteNode* _character;
....
 SKTexture* tmp = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:string];
            tmp.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

            [textureArray addObject:tmp];
            _character = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:tmp];
```

Then under a certain condition in the game, if I check it satisfied, I will change the appearance by:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
if (condition_satisfied) {
...
_store.position = _character.position;

[_character removeFromParent];
...
//load new character texture here, I won't post the code, for short. Then
....
_character.position = _store.position;
...
[self addChild:_character];
}
```

I use a store node to store the position, because my character's position will change during the game by human touch. But in the game, it will always cause crash,  collision... So I guess that is not the right way to restore the right position of character.
How should I do here ?

Comment: What does the crash message say? What kind of object is _store.position?

Comment: There is no error message. The game simply reset due to the collision condition is satisfy, which means the new position causes the character to collide with objects in the scene. store is a node just to store the position of character: SKSpriteNode* _store;

Comment: Please log the error message you get when the game crashes?

Answer (score 0):

To change a texture just set `SKSpriteNode`'s `texture` property:

```
_character.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"image"];
```

Or use `SKAction`, if you want to add some fading effect when texture is changing:

```
SKAction *fadeOut = [SKAction fadeOutByDuration:0.3f];
SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction fadeInByDuration:0.3f];
SKAction *changeTexture = [SKTexture setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"image"]];
[_character runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[fadeOut,changeTexture,fadeIn]]];
```

There is no need to `removeFromParent` the node.

If you need to store node's position, it's better to store it in `@property`:

```
@interface GameScene()

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint characterPosition;

@end

@implementation GameScene

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
if (condition_satisfied) {
...
self.characterPosition = _character.position;

[_character removeFromParent];
...
//load new character texture here, I won't post the code, for short. Then
....
_character.position = self.characterPosition;
...
[self addChild:_character];
}

@end
```

Comment: I cannot find setTexture in my xcode. I think it is only for iOs 7.1 isn't it ? How to work with older method ?

Comment: No, it works for 7.0+. Check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/setTexture:

Comment: The right way to write it in my editor is: SKAction* changeTexture = [SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"imagename"]]; I don't now why I need fade in, out; looks like can live without it. The only problem is my character currently have runAction already, after changing texture by this, it change the texture but not run action anymore. I put the action inside the sequence but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a SKSpriteNode to store the position of the node, you can simply do so in a `CGPoint` variable.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
if (condition_satisfied) {
...
CGPoint characterPosition = _character.position;

[_character removeFromParent];
...
//load new character texture here, I won't post the code, for short. Then
....
_character.position = characterPosition;
...
[self addChild:_character];
}
```